# What value for "build" for npm run build?

Tags: node.js

> Error: missing script: build

When no `build` in package.json for `npm run build --configuration` for my node **API** project. It runs F5 development ok.

Not sure what values to be and anything else?

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "?What values here?",
    ...
  },
```

Here is rest of package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.11.5",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cookies": "^0.8.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "formidable": "^1.2.2",
    "make-runnable": "^1.3.6",
    "mv": "^2.1.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-watch": "^7.0.0"
  }
```

launch.json

```
 "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\server.js",
        }
    ],
```

Node version is 14. VSC 1.63.1, windows 10

Comment: Can you give more details about the project ? What does it do ?
What "build" does, depends on the purpose of the project. If it's a regular node.js app, then you don't need a build command.

Comment: @Medteck It's an API project mainly returning JSONs. If a build command is not needed, how to link all packages, minify .js and distribution?